# Android can't access a web server?

Tags: java, android, apache

So I've got a little script set up on my server that says whether a user is log in able or not. When accessing the url http:server-url/username/password/ I would get a string returned called "correct" or "incorrect".

What I'm doing in my Android app is the following:

```
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String url = "http://server-url/"+usernameText+"/"+passwordHash+"/";
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            try {
                String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, handler);
                Log.e("logged in",response);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                Log.e("clientprotocolexception",e.toString());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("ioexception","error");
        }
```

I'm getting an error:

```
 04-29 14:31:15.728: ERROR/clientprotocolexception(9366): org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: FORBIDDEN
```

but the website itself works fine when I just access it through the browser? Are these some settings I have to set correctly somewhere on the server, or am I forgetting something in my code?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to check your `userNameText` and `passwordHash` - the server is saying they are incorrect and you are forbidden to access the page. I suspect you're not URL encoding them properly.

Comment: You are sending a POST request, maybe a GET request is expected.

Comment: It seems that the server is responding with a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403 code. The problem is likely to be on the server side, not in your application. Or your application does not provide enough data (credentials, http headers, ...) to the server.

Comment: @Jcs, yep that's fixed it! Seems completely obvious in hind sight, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using Post instead of Get, JCs answered it in the comments on my original question.

Answer (score 1):

Did you think of giving the internet permission?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: Yeah, I have given it internet permission.

Answer (score 0):

Use this [example](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/branches/4.0.x/httpclient/src/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientAuthentication.java) to guide you to pass username password and credentials, instead of using the url.

Comment: What makes this better than using the URL? I can't immediately see any benefits? (this is probably me just missing something in reading that code?)

Comment: @Simon Just giving an alternative, in case there was some problem in processing the url.